# IOS App crash GAIThread- Google Tag Manager Implementation

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I have a IOS app in which Google Analytics is been implemented by using Google Tag Manager, very recently I have been noticing crash in App (IOS)

The issue is related to GAIThread, below link which has details of this issue similar to one i am getting

[Threading crash in Google Analytics for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750038/threading-crash-in-google-analytics-for-ios)

Last Exception Backtrace:
0 CoreFoundation 0x2249c7ef8 __exceptionPreprocess + 228
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x223b95a40 objc_exception_throw + 55
2 CoreFoundation 0x2248df154 -[NSObject+ 217428 (NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 139

Comment: What's your question/problem, *exactly*? Could you add more information/context?

Comment: I also have this issue, have you found any solutions?